# Are there any complete examples of using winhttp in C on windows?

Tags: c, windows, winhttp

I can find tons of examples in C++, but nothing that's written in just C. I am trying to connect to an http server, download the returned data, and then save it to a file. Is there a better way to do it on Windows? Should I not be using WinHttp or WinInet? Windows documentation for C seems to be extremely lacking on the internet. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Um, the entire Windows API is written in C and extensively documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee663300%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/internet/http/article.php/c6237
also this looks good and in C
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384270(v=VS.85).aspx#Downloading_resource
This question has also been asked and answered here
[How to download a file with WinHTTP in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822714/how-to-download-a-file-with-winhttp-in-c-c)

Comment: its mix of C/C++