# C++ Download file from internet with Winhttp

Tags: c++, winhttp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to download a file with WinHTTP in C/C++ ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822714/how-to-download-a-file-with-winhttp-in-c-c)

Hello! I have a simple question. How can you download a file from specific http page with the help of Winhttp in C++? 
Note: I want to use this function for a console application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try to read the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc716528.aspx)