# Prevent winHTTP From Writing to STDOUT

Tags: c++, stdout, winhttp

I've taken the following code from a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822714/how-to-download-a-file-with-winhttp-in-c-c) SO post:

```
//Variables
DWORD dwSize = 0;
DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
LPSTR pszOutBuffer;
std::vector <std::string>  vFileContent;
BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
HINTERNET  hSession = NULL,
           hConnect = NULL,
           hRequest = NULL;

// Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
hSession = WinHttpOpen( L"WinHTTP Example/1.0",
                        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
                        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
                        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

// Specify an HTTP server.
if (hSession)
    hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession, L"stackoverflow.com",
                               INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0);

// Create an HTTP request handle.
if (hConnect)
    hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, L"GET", L"/questions/ask/",
                                   NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
                                   NULL,
                                   NULL);

// Send a request.
if (hRequest)
    bResults = WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest,
                                   WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
                                   0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0,
                                   0, 0);


// End the request.
if (bResults)
    bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL);

// Keep checking for data until there is nothing left.
if (bResults)
    do{
        // Check for available data.
        dwSize = 0;
        if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable( hRequest, &dwSize))
            printf( "Error %u in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n",
                    GetLastError());

        // Allocate space for the buffer.
        pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize+1];
        if (!pszOutBuffer)
        {
            printf("Out of memory\n");
            dwSize=0;
        }
        else
        {
            // Read the Data.
            ZeroMemory(pszOutBuffer, dwSize+1);

            if (!WinHttpReadData( hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer,
                                  dwSize, &dwDownloaded))
            {
                printf( "Error %u in WinHttpReadData.\n",
                        GetLastError());
            }
            else
            {
                        printf("%s", pszOutBuffer);
                            // Data in vFileContent
                vFileContent.push_back(pszOutBuffer);
            }

            // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
            delete [] pszOutBuffer;
        }

    } while (dwSize>0);


// Report any errors.
if (!bResults)
    printf("Error %d has occurred.\n",GetLastError());

// Close any open handles.
if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);

// Write vFileContent to file
std::ofstream out("./SO/ask.html",std::ios::app);
for (int i = 0; i < (int) vFileContent.size();i++)
out << vFileContent[i];
out.close();
```

When run it downloads the file and prints it's data. I looked through the code, and couldn't find where it was writing the data to STDOUT. Can someone tell me where it's coming from and how to prevent it?

Comment: Line `printf("%s", pszOutBuffer);` looks suspiciously.

Comment: Link to previous post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
printf("%s", ppszOutBuffer);
```

I believe is the reason here.